# jQuery form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been working on this jQuery form which would only allow the user to submit once all fields are filled in. So essentially, the submit field (or in my case the 'request' field) is dimmed until all fields are not blank. My button is always dimmed though, would someone help me with this please? I have the following jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var $submit = $(".request input");
    var $required = $(".required");
    function containsBlanks(){
        var blanks = $required.map(function(){ return $(this).val() == "";});
        // the inArray helper method checks if value is within an array
        return $.inArray(true, blanks) != -1;
    }

    function requiredFilledIn(){
        if(containsBlanks()) 
        $submit.attr("disabled","disabled");
    else 
        $submit.removeAttr("disabled");
    }

    $("#form2 span").hide();
    $("input").focus(function(){
        $(this).next().fadeIn("slow");
    }).blur(function(){
        $(this).next().fadeOut("slow");
    }).keyup(function(){
        //Check all required fields.
        requiredFilledIn();
    });

    requiredFilledIn();
});
```

This is my form

```
    <div id="form2" title="Request a Call-back">
        <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required. The submit button will activate once this is done.</p>
        <form action="includes/requestcall.php" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" class="required" />
                <span>Please enter your Name</span>
                <br />
                <br />
                <label for="number">Number:</label>
                <input type="text" name="number" id="number" size="30" class="required" />
                <span>Please enter your number</span>
                <br />
                <br />
                <label for="time">Preferred Time:</label>
                <input type="text" name="time" id="time" size="30" class="required" />
                <span>Please enter your preferred time</span>
                <br />
            </fieldset>
            <p class="request">
            <input type="submit" value="Request" class="btn-submit">
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
```

I'm still learning jQuery and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why the inArray check?  If you have any results comeback in the map function then you know that you have incomplete textboxes.

Comment: @JustinMichaels without the inArray check my submit button is always active, I want it inactive until all the fields are filled in.

Comment: Please don't tag the question with [tag:jquery-validate] unless you're using the jQuery Validate plugin.  Thanks.  Edited.

Comment: @Sparky That wasn't me. Another user added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've adjusted the code slightly to use the filter function to retrieve the empty textboxes along with using the change event.

[This is the link to the updated script running your markup on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/justinmichaels/Vwf4b/)

Here's the updated script:

```
$(function () {
    var $submit = $("input.btn-submit").attr("disabled", "disabled").css("color", "red");
    var $required = $(".required");

    function requiredFilledIn() {
        var blanks = $required.filter(function () {
            return $(this).val() === "";
        });
        if (blanks.length > 0) $submit.attr("disabled", "disabled").css("color", "red");
        else $submit.removeAttr("disabled").css("color", "black");
    }

    $("#form2 span").hide();
    $("input:text").focus(function () {
        $(this).next().fadeIn("slow");
    }).blur(function () {
        $(this).next().fadeOut("slow");
    }).change(function () {
        //Check all required fields.
        requiredFilledIn();
    });
});
```

Comment: You could probably paste the contents of requiredFilledIn function in the body of the change event.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I had another issue which I figured out as well from earlier. I will look into the filter function. I can't explain how much I appreciate your efforts especially providing me with the link on JSFiddle. Take care. @JustinMichaels